# diagonal value in co-occurrence matrix

Tags: matrix, cross-product

I am so newbie and thank you so much in advance for advice

I want to make co-occurrence matrix, and followed link below

[How to use R to create a word co-occurrence matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668505/how-to-use-r-to-create-a-word-co-occurrence-matrix)

but I cannot understand why value of A-A is 10 in the matirx below
It should be 4 isn't it? because there are four A

> dat <- read.table(text='film tag1 tag2 tag3

- 1      A    A    A
- 2      A    C    F
- 3      B    D    C ', header=T)

> crossprod(as.matrix(mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(dat[, -1])))))

( ) A   C   F   B   D

A 10  1  1  0  0

C  1  2  1  1  1

F  1  1  1  0  0

B  0  1  0  1  1

D  0  1  0  1  1

Answer (score 1):

The solution you use presumes each tag appears only once per film, which jives with the definition of a co-occurrence matrix as far as I can tell. Therefore, each `A` on the first line gets counted as co-occurring with itself and with the other two `A`s, resulting in a total of ten co-occurences when factoring in the `A` on the second line.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I got it

Comment: @Charley You're welcome. You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark icon under the vote count.